# Updating a dictionary from list

Tags: python

How can i update a dictionary with keys from a list dict_keys and values from a list dict_values? I have tried using for loop in this way:

```
for i in dict dict_keys:
    for o in dict_values:
        dict(i) = o
```

Comment: please add sample input and corresponding expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary using a dictionary comprehension. The `zip` function creates an iterator that will return a set with one item from each list, just like a zipper joins two sides of teeth. You can then combine one key and one value `k:v` for each corresponding pair.

```
dict = {k:v for k, v in zip(dict_keys, dict_values)}
```

If you already have a `dict` and you just want to update it with these values, simply call the `update()` function on it with the same comprehension:

```
dict.update({k:v for k, v in zip(dict_keys, dict_values)})
```